# Beginner Help: Drawing Lines

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to make the word 'Hi' in lines in java code. It is an assignment.

When I draw a line, I have to enter 4 numbers. What do each of the numbers actually represent? Please can someone tell me in a very beginner way?

This is the code so far:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

g2d.drawString("Hello World!",100,100);
g2d.drawLine(80, 50, 80,150);
g2d.drawLine(160, 50, 160, 150);
g2d.drawLine(50, 80, 150, 80);
g2d.drawLine(200, 50, 200, 150);

}
```

Comment: The `x` and `y` coordinates of the two points.

Comment: Please learn how to [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be trivially explained by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
```

[image]

Draws a line between the points `(x1, y1)`and `(x2, y2)`.read oracle api [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)

update....
seems you have confused with Cartesian coordinate system.
take a look at xy coordinate system.

top left represent 0,0 coordinate .
think if you use `g2d.drawLine(4, 2, 8,1);` following output will be recieved .there is no need to x1,y1 to be the same .

[image]

Comment: so, x1 and y1 need to be the same?

Comment: @Dalzar no no.why do you think it should be same .you should take a look of coordinate system

Comment: Sorry, I get all confused.. if x1 and y1 are different, how doe sit calculate where to put the point?

Comment: @Dalzar Do you know how a coordinate system works??? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system or a simpler explanation: http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/cartesian-coordinates.html

Comment: @Dalzar check my updated answer..take a closer look at image

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), the name of the parameters are: `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2`. So the coordinates of the first and the second point.

The [`Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) class considers a raster with the size the *width* and the *height* of the image/frame you are writing to. The difference with mathematical graphs is that the *y*-axis moves downwards so:

```
+---------------------------->
|0                         x
|
|
| y
v
```